# What is a railway-share?

Tags: meaning, literature

In *The Hunting of the Snark* by Lewis Carroll there is a repeated line:

> You may threaten its life with a railway-share.

What is a railway-share in this context?  All I can find is shares as in stock, but how would you threaten someone or something's life with this?

Comment: You wouldn't. The hunting of the snark is a nonsense poem. The whole point is nothing makes sense.

Comment: Never read this poem but it sounds like you're threatening to share the railway between the snark and a train. Obviously, train wins.

Comment: [...reach into your pocket for **the railway share mentioned earlier.** What the Snark lacks in intelligence it has plenty in smarts - as you will soon see for yourself. The share will get snatched from your hand if you are not careful. It doesn't matter much if the Snark actually dies from the **share poison,** or the terrible noise the railroad makes.](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/A_Guide_to_Snark_Hunting_-_An_Edwardian_Gentlemen%27s_Companion) As I recall, railway shares were traditionally dipped in curare, so antique ones should always be handled with kid gloves (just kidding! :)

Comment: It means a share in a railway company. As Dan says, the poem is deliberate nonsense.

Comment: I had previously assumed, from context, that the reference was to a railroad tie -- the wood crossbeam of a railroad track. But on closer examination, I see a ploughSHARE refers to the metal blade of a plow, which could more likely correspond to a length of metal railroad rail -- swordlike, but too heavy for anyone but Superman or a giant to lift!

Comment: @OwenKL In British English the cross-ties are called *sleepers*. Shares have no place on the railway.

Answer (score 8):

There is no doubt that it means a share in a railway company. Carroll's readers would have understood that straight away.

Comment: Yes: Carroll was writing during the [Railway Mania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Mania).

Comment: The key-point being that because of the massive speculation around them, and their subsequent collapse, most railway shares were an excellent way of losing you money for many of the people that bought them. In so far as there is any meaning in The Snark, threatening someone with a railway-share would, presumably, have meant threatening them with bankruptcy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be on the safe side, then call the Snark "nonsense". That's the low risk approach to "The Hunting to the Snark".

However, Carroll himself stated that "The Hunting of the Snark" is about the search for happiness. Some (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Mania) tried their luck by investing railway shares, e.g. Charles Darwin (http://darwin-online.org.uk/content/frameset?pageseq=103&itemID=A668&viewtype=text). Some earned a fortune, others were less lucky.

Answer (score 0):

The word “snark” is, among other things, related closely to pigs - through “snork and “snorker” (English Dialect Dictionary, Vol.5, p. 572). This connection is strongly supported in Carroll’s poem by the fact that in it he makes a great many references to pigs. In 1870, almost six years before the publication of The Snark, a new railway line was opened between Garstang and Pilling, in Lancanshire, England. The line was later nicknamed The Pilling Pig, because:

> "One of the earlier engines on the line had a particularly piercing whistle, which reminded some hearers of the sounds made by a pig in the process
> of being slaughtered." (Dave Richardson quoted in The Mail, March 13, 2019)

This “pig” was purchased in 1875. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garstang_and_Knot-End_Railway)

Moreover, this line, better known as The Garstag & Knot End Railway, had ongoing insolvency problems due to the fact they could never sell enough railway-shares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garstang_and_Knot-End_Railway), and:

> "For most of its independent existence, the Garstang & Knott End Railway remained hopelessly insolvent and ordinary shareholders never received a penny of dividend interest on their shares. ("Dave Richardson quoted in The Mail, March 13, 2019)

Therefore these particular railway-shares were toxic for both the pig/Snark - by never raising enough cash to properly fund the railway line - and for the share-holders who never saw a return on their investments.

Comment: It seems to require a chain of unsupported speculations to link this to the _Snark_

Comment: If you want much longer pieces, explaining some of the above, especially the very intricate links between the Snark and pigs,  and much more, you could have a look at my two papers - ‘The Consumption of the Snark and the Decline of Nonsense (in ‘The Carrollian’  #8, 2001) or The Bellman, Rituals of Death and the April Fool in The Hunting of the Snark (in ‘Knight Letter’ #60, 1999).